# Liquibase: setDefaultSchema is not working

Tags: mysql, liquibase, database-schema, multi-tenant

I am creating Schema-Based Multi Tenant application with spring boot(2.5.2) , mySQL 8.0 and Liquibae 4.4.1.

I expect that all my tenant tables and liquibase internal tables should be created inside a tenant schema which I specify before running the migration.

```
liquibase.setDefaultSchema(tenantSchema); --sets the schema for changesets
liquibase.setLiquibaseSchema(tenantSchema); -- sets schema for liquibase internal tables
```

I can see that liquibase internal tables are getting created inside tenant schema correctly .

But liquibase is always executing my changesets against public schema. Looks like setting the deafult schema prior to liquibase migration has no effect. I am using sql-based changesets and I don't want to switch to xml.

I found a workaround but it is risky . I am looking for a better solution.

Workaround:

Before running migration, I save current tenant's schema in a jvm argumanet as below

```
System.setProperty("changeSetSchemaName", tenant.getSchema());
```

Then in my change set , I read this schema value and explicitly set the schema name as below

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset author-id:alter_xxx_table
use ${changeSetSchemaName}          --switch to tenant schema
alter table table_name add column new_column data_type;     --execute sql
use master;    --switch back to master schema                                          
--rollback ....
```

This does work but I am forced to change every single changeset. If I forget to do this then some unexpected stuff will happen. I can add unit test to parse the changesets and verify that schema statements are used before and after the sql (I will have to do this in case I dont get any solution) .

It will be great if someone knows a risk-free solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two arguments [liquibaseSchemaName and defaultSchemaName](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/liquibase-schema-name-parameter.html?Highlight=default%20Schema%20Name). liquibaseSchemaName is for internal liquibase tables and defaultSchemaName specifies the default schema name to use for the database connection.

Comment: The page you linked doesn't mention defaultSchemaName.